# Como hago para que devuelva un 0 en el DNI y lo llame el bloque anonimo

Tags: sql, sql-server

**OBTIENE_ALUMNO**:  función que devuelve los datos del alumno  a partir de su dni (si no existe debe devolver valor 0 en el dni).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OBTIENE_ALUMNO (V_DNI IN ALUMNOS.DNI%TYPE)
  RETURN ALUMNOS%ROWTYPE
IS
  V_ALUMNO ALUMNOS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO V_ALUMNO FROM ALUMNOS WHERE DNI=V_DNI;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('0');
END OBTIENE_ALUMNO;
```

- Ver la parte de `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('0');`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con los returns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OBTIENE_ALUMNO (V_DNI IN ALUMNOS.DNI%TYPE)
  RETURN ALUMNOS%ROWTYPE
IS
  V_ALUMNO ALUMNOS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO V_ALUMNO FROM ALUMNOS WHERE DNI=V_DNI;
  RETURN V_ALUMNO;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    V_ALUMNO.DNI = 0;
    RETURN V_ALUMNO;
END OBTIENE_ALUMNO;
```